# How do you get the button name/tag when the event button.click occurs?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I'm making buttons programatically and adding them to a stack panel so the buttons change each time the user navigates to the page. I'm trying to do something like this where when I click the created button it'll grab the tag of the button and go to the correct page. However, I can't access the button elements using RoutedEventHandler. Here's the code:

```
foreach (item in list)
{ 
   Button newBtn = new Button();
   newBtn.Content = "Button Text";
   newBtn.Tag = item.Tag;
   newBtn.Name = item.Name;
   newBtn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(newBtn_Click);
}

private void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + sender.Tag, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pretty simple just cast the sender to a Button Object  an you will  get all button properties

```
  private void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + ((Button)sender).Tag, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

```
(sender as Button).Tag
```

Should work.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of solutions here.  The first is to simple check and see if the sender of the event was a `Button` element and use the information there

```
private void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button b = sender as Button;
  if (b != null) { 
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + b.Tag, UriKind.Relative));
  }
}
```

Another more type safe / friendly option is to create a lambda to handle the event which directly accesses the `Button` instance you want

```
foreach (item in list)
{ 
   Button newBtn = new Button();
   newBtn.Content = "Button Text";
   newBtn.Tag = item.Tag;
   newBtn.Name = item.Name;
   newBtn.Click += (sender, e) => {
     NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/DetailPage.xaml?selectedItem=" + newBtn.Tag, UriKind.Relative));
   };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int tag = (sender as Button).Tag
```

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758286.aspx

Button b = sender as Button;
// your logic here