# Is there a way to dynamically generate code to interact with buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to find a a way to be able to essentially dynamically generate code based on an input.

For example I could type something like:

```
int Number = 22;
Button<Number>.Text = "X";
```

So in this case it would set button22 to have its text be an "X".

And I could change it so that I could input, for example 24 into the program and it would then set button24 to be an "X", instead of setting up a bunch of if statements to cover every potential button press.

For further context I have a Grid of 64 buttons and I need to be able to edit them individually to show to the user which buttons have been pressed, it is possible to do it with a lot of if statements but I thought it might be worth trying to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Save all buttons in list/array and use indexer to acces them.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, UWP... the short answer is of course yes, but visual studio tag is not relevant

Comment: please include a snippet of how you add the button to the UI, as in how you define it's layout or visual state. That way we can provide a specific example and not be shooting in the dark when this can be achieved in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a list of buttons:

```
private List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>();
```

Populate it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var b = new Button();
        b.Text = $"Button #{i}";
        b.Click += HandleButtonClick;
    }
```

And you could even set an event handler on one of its events which doesn't even need to use the list (the `sender` is the source of the event):

```
private void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Text = "X";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buttons have a Tag property that can be used to hold arbitrary data about a button, this is described for [WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netframework-4.8), [WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=netframework-4.8) and [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.tag#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_Tag).
Simple usage that is similar to OP's requirement is demonstrated in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20540928/1690217)

This situation is in a practical sense the very reason that `.Tag` exists at all in user interface controls pretty much from the birth of c#.

So you do not need to use a custom class for a button, just simply assign your value to the `.Tag` property on the `Button` class that you are creating programmatically:

> in this example a list is used to create the buttons and separate the creation from the layout, it is not necessary to do this, but may be useful. Instead, you could assign this button to it's parent container and/or set the layout margins or coordinates without keeping a reference to the `Button` object at all.
>   If OP updates the post to include implementation examples, we can update this response with more specific and complete code.

```cs
private List<Button> _buttons = new List<Button>();
// ... iteration or switching logic 
var nextButton = new Button 
{ 
    Text = "x",
    Tag = 22
};
nextButton.Click += DynamicButton_Click;
_buttons.Add(nextButton);

// ... later push the buttons into the parent container or bind to the UI
```

Then the button click handler you can access this Tag property:

> this is presented from WinForms, the only difference in UWP or WPF is the method signature, change `EventArgs` to `RoutedEventArgs`

```
private void DynamicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(int.TryParse((sender as Button).Tag?.ToString(), out int buttonValue))
    {
        // use buttonValue
        Console.Out.WriteLine(buttonValue);
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, sender was not a button, or the button did not have an integer tag value
        // either way, handle that error state here...
    }
}
```

Using these concepts, once the buttons are created, let's say in some simple grid alignment, you could allow the user to set this `Tag` value at runtime if you have a TextBox (or other) input field that can be accessed from the code.

> I recommend that you use MVVM style bindings for this rather than directly referencing a TextBox control, but this is simply to demonstrate the point.

```
private void DynamicButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // assign the string value from the ButtonValueTextbox control to this button
    string value = this.ButtonValueTextBox.Text;
    if(sender is Button button)
    {
        button.Tag = value;
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise, sender was not a button
        // handle the error state here if you need to...
    }
}
```

> Now that each button has a tag, you could easily add logic to maintain unique tag values by iterating through the other buttons and clearing the tag if it was previously assigned to a different button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could keep a `List` of `Button` `References`:

```cs
var myButtons = new List<Button>();
myButtons.Add(firstButton);
myButtons.Add(secondButton);

// ... etc

// ... then somewhere else 

int number = 3;
myButtons[number].Text = "xxx";
```